# SO Jobs bug after applying

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm experiencing a bug when applying for a job offer on [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

After I fill-in the submission form and click submit, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8pKy.jpg). Clicking outside (or anywhere else) does nothing to dismiss this empty popup box.

Today was the third time it exhibited in a month or so.

Comment: that's interesting... do you see any errors on your developer console? my guess is that your ads blocker is filtering one of our JS files

Comment: yes, exactly that was the cause. there are many similar reports with similar conclusions.

Comment: yup, I dealt with a bunch of them. I'm adding this to our bugs board. Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: @nullpotent Note that it's more appropriate in circumstances such as this to provide a self-answer, rather than replace your question with the answer.  This allows others to find the same problem/solution, rather than reporting another duplicate.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion @MichaelGaskill

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by uBlock filtering one of our JS files. I fixed it so that if uBlock filters the analytics services (which it does by default) our site keeps on working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like uBlock extension for Chrome is the cause.

Disabling (whitelisting blocked cdn resources) it fixed the issue.

---

Here's the log from uBlock of blocked resources (marked with yellow & red)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmm, so three different tracking services now know you applied for a job.  Useful that.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please explain what you mean? I feel stupid. I mean, what's the significance of your statement?

Comment: @HansPassant Ah ok, knew that already. So you were being sarcastic :)